# How can I redirect an already logged user to Index in Asp .Net Core web Application (razor pages)

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, authentication, web-applications, razor-pages

I want to avoid users getting into the login page if already authenticated.

I know that you can use the `RedirectToPage("/index")` but i don`t know were.

I've tried this:

```cs
@page
@model xxxxx.Accounts.LoginModel
@{
    Layout = "EmptyLayout";
    if (User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
          RedirectToPage("/index")
}

<!doctype html>
<html lang="es">
//login page
```

This don't work for me and I know that `if (User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)` is true, and in the **PageModel** the `Redirect("")` method works properly.

Is there any **PageModel** method like *OnCreate()*, *OnLoad()*,...  to run code before the page is loaded? How can I achive this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I belive that i was not on debug mode so i didn't get the breakpoint on the `OnGet()`. So the solution is just to do this:

```cs
public async Task<IActionResult> OnGet()
        {
            if (User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
                return Redirect("/Index");
            else return Page();

        }
```

Answer (score 0):

As you tested, the onget method is occurred when the page loading.

Besides, if you want to get other method which is early than the onget method. I suggest you could try filter method.

Razor Page filters:

> Run code after a handler method has been selected, but before model
> binding occurs.
>
> Run code before the handler method executes, after model binding is
> complete.
>
> Run code after the handler method executes.
>
> Can be implemented on a page or globally.
>
> Cannot be applied to specific page handler methods.
>
> Can have constructor dependencies populated by Dependency Injection
> (DI). For more information, see ServiceFilterAttribute and
> TypeFilterAttribute.

More details about how it works ,you could refer to this [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/razor-pages/filter?view=aspnetcore-6.0).